# Deploy pre-written SpringMVC + Hibernate to AWS

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Basically, I've already written a webapp, it has hibernate with SpringMVC + Spring-security.

I have an EC2 account, my question is, when deploying it to the cloud rather than on a server locally like I do now (with RDS rather than having MySQL on localhost like I do now), should I just copy the war over onto the Tomcat installation of EC2, or do everything through Eclipse?

Is it relatively straight forward to set the new Hibernate.cfg.xml to point at a RDS rather than localhost?

At the moment I just copy the war onto the server and use iptables to map 80 to 8080, but I think I'm taking a very long route for deployment...I've not setup the db layer yet remotely...

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am used to deploying WAR files to EC2 instances (though using WebLogic instead of Tomcat), and I think it is much more straightforward just to FTP the files over to the EC2 instance rather than trying to deploy them through Eclipse.
For your other question, it is completely straightforward pointing Hibernate.cfg.xml to RDS. You will probably have no issues doing so, as long as you remember to give the correct permissions on RDS. Hope it helps.

Comment: Do you still use Jenkins or Hudson locally?

Comment: Ah ok, so you have a server locally dedicated for jenkins, then that builds your war, then you manually deploy the war over to the weblogic on ec2?

Comment: Yes. I could also have Jenkins deploy it automatically (through Maven), but since we go through QA and other processes before doing so, we do it manually.